# connect step function to 0 and max y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this code as example:

```
df <- data.frame(
        x = c(30, 40, 20, 60)
        , y = c(10, 20, 5, 70)
        , group = c("g1", "g1", "g2", "g2") 
    )

options(repr.plot.width = 10, repr.plot.height = 7) 
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group)) +
    geom_step(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group), size=1) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 100, by = 5), 1)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))
```

It produces:

[image]

Is there an easy way in ggplot (?) to achieve the following (only indicated by one step function):

[image]

Or do I need to change original data and somehow impute? Hope this makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: I've had a similar problem, I did a quick and slightly dirty solution which is to add two if statements. One for the min saying if y >0 then rbind a new coordinate (x,0) and similarly for the max value. I'm sure there is a better solution though

Comment: Do you only need to change group1? You will need to add the 0,0 point and the 60,20 point into the data. They are the two endpoints.

Comment: Thanks all no sorry I need it for all groups. I only used 2 as an example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add rows for each group's starting and ending points to match the desired result:

```r
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x, x=c(0, Inf), y=c(0, max(.x$y))))

#  group     x     y
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 g1       30    10
#2 g1       40    20
#3 g1        0     0
#4 g1      Inf    20
#5 g2       20     5
#6 g2       60    70
#7 g2        0     0
#8 g2      Inf    70

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_step(size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 100, by = 5), 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100), xlim = c(20,60))
```

[image]

---

Or, if you want this only for the first group (same idea; but not by group):

```r
df %>% 
  add_row(., group = "g1", x = c(0, Inf), y = c(0, max(.$y[.$group == "g1"]))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_step(size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 100, by = 5), 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100), xlim = c(20,60))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. did not know about these dplyr constructs. Guess you mean max(.y$y) instead of max(.x$y)?

Comment: No, I mean `.x$y`, because `.x` refers to the group. So `.x$y` is column y of each group. `max(.y$y)` should return an error.

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused. Let us say my true x and y is called x1 and y1 would the syntax be:  group_modify(~ add_row(.x, x1=c(0, Inf), y1=c(0, max(.x$y1))))

Comment: Exactly. That's it.